# Juego de piedra papel o tijera en HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo una app pequeña de piedra, papel o tijera y básicamente esta compuestas por un documento HTML (main.html) para la parte de "login y otro documento HTML (options.html) para la parte del juego. Ambos archivos conectados a un mismo archivo JS (main.js). El problema es que a pesar de haber definido todos los elementos de los dos documentos html en el JS, los elementos de la parte del juego no son leídos en la parte login. y no sé como de alguna forma conectarlos. Por si no me he explicado bien aqui dejo una imagen de los archivos y mi código respectivamente (por favor ignorar los archivos box.js y app.js).

[image: imagen donde se muestran los archivos de mi proyecto]

```html
<!--parte login-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/style.css">
  <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>

</head>

<body onload="game()">
  <div class="principalContainer">
    <h1 class="title">Rock Paper or Scissors Game</h1>
    <div class="players">
      <div class="playerOne" id="playerOne">
        <p class="text-player">Put Your Name Player One</p>
        <input type="text" name="" id="input" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton" id="plusButton"><p class="plus">+</p></i>
      </div>
      <div id="oponente" class="oponent">
        <a href="#oponente"><input type="button" id="computer" value=".VS Computer"></a>
        <a href="#playertwo"><input type="button" id="player" value=" .VS Player"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="playertwo" class="playerTwo">
        <p class="text-player-two">Put Your Name Player Two</p>
        <input type="text" name="" id="input-two" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton-two" id="plusButton-two"><p class="plus-two">+</p></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="playLink">
      <a href="options.html" class="game">Let´s Play Folks!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="seeStats">
      <a href="#stats" class="statsButton">See Stadistics</a>
    </div>
    <div id="stats" class="modal" onload="stadistics()">
      <a href="#"><img src="../img/x-mark.png" alt="exit" class="exit"></a>
      <div class="stats">
        <img src="../img/refresh.png" alt="refresh" class="refresh" id="refresh">
        <p class="statsTitle">Stadistics</p>
        <ul class="gameList" id="gameList">
          <!--<li>
                        <p class="player">Player1</p>
                        <p class="finalScore">0:3</p>
                        <p class="secondPlayer">Player2</p>
                    </li>-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../main.js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!--parte juego-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/gameStyle.css">
    <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" onload="game()">
        <div class="playerPoints" id="playerPoints">
            PlayerName
        </div>
        <div class="scoreboard">
            <p class="points" id="points">0:0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="enemyPoints" id="enemyPoints">
            comp/player2
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="turnText" id="turnText">
                Your turn Player 1</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="options">
            <div class="rockContainer">
                <img src="../img/fist.png" alt="rock" class="rock" id="rock">
            </div>
            <div class="paperContainer">
                <img src="../img/hand.png" alt="paper" class="paper" id="paper">
            </div>
            <div class="scissorsContainer">
                <img src="../img/scissors.png" alt="scissors" class="scissors" id="scissors">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert">
            <p class="winner" id="winner">Paper cover Rock. You won player one!</p>
        <a href="main.html" class="newGame" id="newGame">Lets go to the menu!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../main.js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict";


//selecting DOM elements

//login page
const firstInput= document.getElementById("input");
const firstPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton");
const compButton= document.getElementById("computer");
const playerButton= document.getElementById("player");
const secondInput= document.getElementById("input-two");
const secondPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton-two");

//stadistics DOM elements
const refresh= document.getElementById("refresh");
const playersList= document.getElementById("gameList");

//game DOM elements
const playerName= document.getElementById("playerPoints");
const points= document.getElementById("points");
const enemyName= document.getElementById("enemyPoints");
const turnText= document.getElementById("turnText");
const rock= document.getElementById("rock");
const paper= document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors= document.getElementById("scissors");
const winnerText= document.getElementById("winner");
const menu= document.getElementById("newGame");

let playerOne= {
    name: "",
    turn: true,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let playerTwo= {
    name: "",
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let computer= {
    name: "Computer",
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}


function game(){
    login();
    versusPlayer();

}
    
function login(){
    

    firstPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
        console.log(playerOne.name);
    })
    document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
        if(event.keyCode===13){
            playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
            console.log(playerOne.name);
        }
    })

    playerButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{ 
            secondPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
                console.log(playerTwo.name);
            })
            document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
                if(event.keyCode===13){
                    playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
                    console.log(playerTwo.name);
                }
            })

            playerName.innerHTML= playerOne.name;
            versusPlayer();
        })


    compButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        console.log(playerOne.name + " vs computer");
        versusComputer();
    })
     
}

function versusPlayer(){
        
        
    if(playerOne.turn===true){
        
        rock.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            console.log("rock")
            playerOne.option= "rock";
            playerOne.turn= false;
            console.log(playerOne.option);
            console.log(playerOne.turn);
        });


        paper.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            playerOne.option= "paper";
            playerOne.turn= false;
            console.log(playerOne.option);
            console.log(playerOne.turn);
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask], pues no se entiende el problema en cuestión

Comment: Cuidado! el evento onload del fichero options.html está en un div y no en el body.

Comment: si disculpen si no se entendió mi problema en cuestión

Comment: pero si alguien entendio el problema y sabe como ayudarme por favor que me lo explique.